# Genymotion - traffic capture

Tags: windows, networking, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

In short, I would like to do in Windows:

1) Redirect **all** the traffic created by the Android VM running in Genymotion (VirtualBox) to my cellular connection (all, not only HTTP).

2) Check that it is the same traffic created by the VM and the one sent to the network. For this, I found out that the applications that monitor network traffic do not work in my VM, and I cannot install apps like tPacketCapture (not compatible). Does anyone know why?

Does anyone know how to do 1) or 2)?

For 1), I am trying to change the network configuration of the VM from VirtualBox but whatever I do it crashes (Unable to connect to your virtual device! error). The VM only works with Adapter 1 in host-only mode, and adapter 2 in NAT. Why does Genymotion need connection anyway?

Thanks in advance